# Знову шукаємо модератора

Tags: discussion, moderation

Я бачу, що мої погляди щодо того, як має розвиватися цей сайт, не збігаються з поглядами інших користувачів, зокрема найактивнішої частини.

Це призводитиме до одного з трьох наслідків: або постійні суперечки, або уникання виконання обов'язків, або кожного разу пересилювати себе й робити всупереч своєму баченню.

Тому оголошую пошук наступника. Поки що «неофіційно» (я не хочу офіційного оголошення, бо боюся, що воно неявно передбачатиме якісь обмеження, наприклад «знайти протягом часу X», а шукати ми можемо дуже довго, і я не хочу, щоб сайт було закрито через такі технічні дрібниці). Допоки заміну мені не знайдено, я виконуватиму обов'язки.

Comment: Зауваження: обовʼязки модератора полягають не лише в перегляді нових дописів (дехто і досі щодня ходить до Review Queues, не посідаючи ніяких посад, з статистикою [приблизно такою](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats)) і embracing нових користувачів (дехто і досі більше за всіх [їх вітає](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users/8/bytebuster?tab=activity&sort=comments), не посідаючи ніяких посад), а також в купі іншої монотонної роботи, якої не видно. Наприклад, теґи. Наприклад, [edits](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Editors&filter=all) […]

Comment: […] Наприклад, чат. Про те, що він у нас frozen, модераторам [було повідомлено](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/5892#comment9374_5892) 20 числа. А 24-го числа модератор, нарешті, натиснув заповітну кнопочку. І так далі. **Тому.** Особисто я переконаний, що кожен може стати модератором без діамантового бейджика, просто будучи активним користувачем/ревʼювером. А бейджик на цю людину ми усі гуртом почепимо. Навіть якщо це доведеться робити силоміць. :-))

Comment: Щось мало охочих відгукнулося. Не бажаєте поставити [featured] ?

Comment: @bytebuster, бо в нас критично мало відвідувачів. Воно й так більшість часу показувалося в «Featured on Meta». Не думаю, що це щось змінить, це наче бити у дзвін у місті, звідки вже майже всіх евакуювали, але добре, поставлю.